# Cakephp ClassRegistry::init problem

Tags: php, cakephp

Please help me on this problem

I have created a component. in the component I have a method like this

```
function storeClick($id = ''){

    if(strlen($id) > 0){
       $ip = $this->RequestHandler->getClientIP();

        $data['FocikiClickDetail']['ip'] = $ip;
        $data['FocikiClickDetail']['photo_id'] = $id;
          $mo = ClassRegistry::init('ClickDetail');

          $mo->save($data);

          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is in the line of this

```
$mo = ClassRegistry::init('ClickDetail');
```

Every time when I delete this line, my application run as usual, otherwise it won't

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have included class registry ?

Comment: how to do that Sahal? I am new to cakephp

Comment: You have model called 'ClickDetail' ?

Comment: yes I do have a model call ClickDetail

Comment: What is the error it says? See here is the class located 'cake/libs/class_registry.php' (Make your error_display var to 1 and past the error here.)

Comment: sorry but where the error_display you mention? is it in php.ini?

Comment: @Sahal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1566/discussion-between-nathanphan-and-sahal)

Comment: How did you answer this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better practice way of loading models in components is to go via the controller, and use loadModel();

In your component, set up the initialize() function, if you haven't already:

```
function initialize($controller, $settings) {
    $this->Controller =& $controller;
}
```

Then in your component function, use loadModel to load the model

```
$this->Controller->loadModel('ClickDetail');
$this->Controller->ClickDetail->save($data);
```

Comment: +1 for better solution.  Although, I would point out that the call-time-pass-by-reference shouldn't be used unless dealing with PHP4.

Comment: Is the call-time-pass-by-reference valid for PHP 5.2.X?  PHP doco suggests that it's only deprecated for PHP 5.3 and onwards.  All my work has been in PHP 5.2 to date.

Comment: It might not trigger an error, so your definition of valid might be different, it's simply unneeded.  They removed the need for call-time-pass-by-reference in PHP 5.  For the portability and future-safeness of your code I wouldn't use call-time-pass-by-reference in PHP 5+.